# IBM Cloud Private 3.1 - unable to login to URL: Unexpected response code 401 from request

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud-private

I have successfully installed IBM Cloud Private 3.1.
All was working well. I could login to the ICP URL, but after rebooting, nothing works.

Now the URL says:

> `Unexpected response code 401 from request: GET
>   https://icp-management-ingress:8443/idmgmt/identity/api/v1/users/admin/getTeamResources?resourceType=namespace
>   HTTP/1.1 Accept: application/json Authorization: bearer *** HTTP/1.1
>   401 Server: openresty/1.11.2.4 Date: Wed, 07 Nov 2018 21:47:55 GMT
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Transfer-Encoding:
>   chunked Connection: close Vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding
>   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
>   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Strict-Transport-Security:
>   max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains X-Download-Options: noopen
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Dns-Prefetch-Control: off
>   {"error":{"statusCode":401,"name":"Error","message":"An error occurred
>   while accessing the kube services rest api"}}`

When I try to login with cloudctl, I get this:

## Cloudctl login

```
API endpoint: https://172.31.16.153:8443
Username> admin
Password>
Authenticating...
OK
Select an account:
1. Mycluster Account (id-mycluster-account)
Enter a number> 1
Targeted account mycluster Account (id-mycluster-account)
FAILED
Error response from server. Status code: 401; message: {"error":{"statusCode":401,"name":"Error","message":"An error occurred while accessing the kube services rest api"}}
```

And kubectl says there is no service for the common ones:

## Kubectl get pods

```
Error: The server doesn't have a resource type "pods"
```

## Kubectl get nodes

```
Error: The server doesn't have a resource type "nodes"
```

## Kubectl get services

```
Error: The server doesn't have a resource type "services"
```

## Kubectl get deployment

```
Error: The server doesn't have a resource type "deployment"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Rebooted what? your laptop?

Comment: rebooted the whole system. Master, management, workers

It seemed that the problem was because I added a servername alias to the /etc/hosts file. In the example below, I was having the problems after I added "master1"
123.123.123.123 ip-123-123-123-123 master1

Comment: So it's fixed then?

Comment: @rico yes - thanks